# Definition of a modular form in terms of differential forms

Tags: differential-forms, modular-forms, complex-manifolds

I have never understood the definition of a modular form in terms of differential forms.  What is formally going on when we rearrange the equation $\frac{gz}{f(z)} = (\frac{d(gz)}{dz})^{-k}$ to the equation $f(gz)d(gz)^k = f(z)dz^k$?

What the formal definition of a "differential form of weight $k$?"  What is meant by $f(z)dz^k$ where $k$ is an integer and $f$ is a meromorphic function on the upper half plane?

I know the basics of differential forms on smooth manifolds.  If $M$ is a real smooth manifold, then a differential $k$-form on $M$ is a smooth section of the map $\Lambda^k (T^{\ast} M) \rightarrow M$, where $T^{\ast} M$ is the contangent bundle of $M$ and $\Lambda^k$ denotes exterior power.

The attached excerpt is from Serre, *A Course in Arithmetic*.

[image]

Comment: You're right, these aren't _exterior_ differential forms (unless $k=1$), but, rather, _symmetric_ forms, formed from the $k$-th symmetric power of the cotangent space/bundle.